# Fail to find class after creating a JVM from C++ application via JNI

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

Using JNI I'm trying to create an instance of a Java class from a C++ project but it fails. I have tested the same code with a simple Java class and it works. The difference is that my actual classpath is a directory containing a bunch of jars. The class I need instantiating `CmaesClient` belongs to one of those jars.

This is the C++ code:

```
JavaVM* jvm = NULL;
JNIEnv *env = NULL;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/azg/code/hpcmom/target/1.1.9-SNAPSHOT/hpcmom-cmaes";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**) &env, &vm_args);
if (jvm == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Failed creating JVM" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Succeeded creating JVM" << std::endl;
}
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com.sfoam.hpcmom.cmaes.CmaesClient");
if (clazz == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Failed creating CmaesClient" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Succeeded creating CmaesClient" << std::endl;
}
jmethodID constr = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        jstring jarPath = env->NewStringUTF("/home/azg/code/hpcmom/target/1.1.9-SNAPSHOT/hpcmom-cmaes/hpcmom-cmaes-1.1.9-SNAPSHOT.jar");
jobject object = env->NewObject(clazz, constr, jarPath);
delete options;
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

and the error meaning it could not find the class, therefore seems something wrong loading the classes or?

```
Succeeded creating JVM
Failed creating CmaesClient
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5601067214, pid=25496, tid=140007371831104
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x645214]  get_method_id(JNIEnv_*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*, bool, Thread*)+0x84
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/azg/code/sfoml/debug/hs_err_pid25496.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The directory `/home/azg/code/hpcmom/target/1.1.9-SNAPSHOT/hpcmom-cmaes` contains all the needed jars.

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is with getting the method, not the class itself... Or does JNI return a non null `jclass` even if it fails to find it?

Comment: The problem is getting the class, see the output `Failed creating CmaesClient`

Comment: Oops, didn't see... But then why do you try and find the method nonetheless then.

Comment: Because it is a WIP :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JNI Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html)

> `name`: a fully-qualified class name (that is, a package name, **delimited
>   by “`/`”**, followed by the class name).

Change

```java
env->FindClass("com.sfoam.hpcmom.cmaes.CmaesClient");
```

to

```java
env->FindClass("com/sfoam/hpcmom/cmaes/CmaesClient");
```

(I.e. replace each `.` with `/`).

Comment: Sorry this actually solves the problem. It was a combination of this and passing every single jar as parameter and not just the jars directory path.